# Javascript serialize window object

Tags: javascript, serialization, xml-serialization

I would like to serialize a window object that contains a window, thus to keep in memory the window open if the php page is refreshed by deserializing it and setting its properties back. Is it Possible?

for example:

`object = window.open("test.html",..)`

Usage Scenario:

When a window is opened its reference is made in the parent window which created it, but when that parent window is refreshed that reference to the child window is lost. Therefore I want to serialize that window object and keep it in case the window is refreshed. Any other solution for this is also welcome.

Comment: could you give a concrete example of a usage scenario for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "that contains window.open"? window.open is a function and I'm confused about how that fits in with what you're trying to ask.

Comment: you actually want to have way to restore page by some serialization? The simplest example - to restore page by URL? If there are few variables to restore, I believe, this can be the simplest way. If there are many degrees of freedom, probably don't try to do it, since it is not trivial task (yet, it is possible, you can use, for example, DOM storage)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can´t serialized a window object. And that's because a window object has circular references. Every child of an object has a reference to his parent. `JSON.stringify()` does not support circular references. And do not try to keep the reference in a global variable. Global variables are properties of a global object. The properties of this object are the global variables of JavaScript programs. When you declare a global JavaScript variable, what you are actually doing is defining a property of the global object.

For more info please check [this link](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_06.htm).